# NMaximize over a Large List: No Output

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

I have a list of 500 sublists of the form:

```
 DifferenceProbability2[α_, χ_, ϕ_, θ_]  = {-0.999401 + 
Re[(0.249863 - 1.47045*10^-18 I) Cos[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.249732 - 0.0155997 I) E^(-2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/2]^2 + (0.249732 + 0.0155997 I) E^(
2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 + (0.250574 - 2.00577*10^-18 I) Sin[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.24981 - 0.00249867 I) E^(-I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.24981 + 0.00249867 I) E^(
I α)
 Cos[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249835 - 0.013099 I) E^(-I α)
 Sin[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249835 + 0.013099 I) E^(
I α)
 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249781 - 
  1.07065*10^-18 I) Sin[χ]^2], -0.997604 + 
 Re[(0.24945 - 1.45012*10^-18 I) Cos[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.248927 - 0.031158 I) E^(-2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/2]^2 + (0.248927 + 0.031158 I) E^(
2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 + (0.252296 + 4.11997*10^-18 I) Sin[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.249239 - 0.00498934 I) E^(-I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249239 + 0.00498934 I) E^(
I α)
 Cos[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249339 - 0.0261526 I) E^(-I α)
 Sin[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249339 + 0.0261526 I) E^(
I α)
 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.249127 + 
  5.14996*10^-19 I) Sin[χ]^2], -0.994616 + 
  Re[(0.248765 + 7.86047*10^-19 I) Cos[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.247588 - 0.0466335 I) E^(-2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/2]^2 + (0.247588 + 0.0466335 I) E^(
2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 + (0.255159 + 9.86624*10^-18 I) Sin[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.248289 - 0.00746405 I) E^(-I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.248289 + 0.00746405 I) E^(
I α)
 Cos[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.248514 - 0.0391156 I) E^(-I α)
 Sin[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.248514 + 0.0391156 I) E^(
I α)
 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.248038 - 
  5.96311*10^-19 I) Sin[χ]^2], -0.990446 + 
  Re[(0.247807 - 3.68629*10^-18 I) Cos[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.24572 - 0.0619853 I) E^(-2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/2]^2 + (0.24572 + 0.0619853 I) E^(
2 I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 + (0.259155 - 4.98733*10^-18 I) Sin[χ/
 2]^4 + (0.246963 - 0.00991488 I) E^(-I α)
 Cos[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.246963 + 0.00991488 I) E^(
I α)
 Cos[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.247363 - 0.0519428 I) E^(-I α)
 Sin[χ/2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.247363 + 0.0519428 I) E^(
I α)
 Sin[χ/
 2]^2 Sin[χ] + (0.246519 + 6.50521*10^-19 I) Sin[χ]^2]}
```

These are just the first 4-5 entries in the list. I want to numerically optimize each entry in the list over $\alpha$ and $\chi$. When I run

```
Optimzation1[α_, χ_, ϕ_, θ_] = 
 NMaximize[{#, 0 <= α <= 2 π, 
  0 <= χ <= π}, {{α, 1, 2}, {χ, 1, 2}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, MaxIterations -> 1000, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 5] & /@ 
     DifferenceProbability2[α, χ, ϕ, θ],
```

the code runs for 40 minutes (for the 500 values) and at the end, it returns nothing -- no output list.

When I try to reproduce the list with

```
 ABC[α_, χ_, ϕ_, θ_] = Optimzation1[α, χ, ϕ, θ],
```

I get nothing. This input command is shown as `In[1]` and it seems as if Mathematica has automatically quit the kernel.

I am able to run the code for 50 sublists in the list. The code runs for abut 5 minutes and gives the result. Nothing for 500 sublists. Possible issues?

Comment: Auto quit is often an indication of insufficient RAM.

Comment: @Feyre How do I figure out in this case, how many computations can Mathematica run in one go? I ideally want to numerically optimize over all the 500 sublists.

Comment: If it's a RAM issue, it's a hardware issue. You can run `MaxMemoryUsed[]`, convert to GB and compare to how much you have available.

Comment: It's easy also to just run the simulation and see how it affects the amount of free memory on the computer, e.g. in the Activity Monitor on Mac OS, or the corresponding tool in Windows.